# Decorating GET method with api.expect() Flask-RESTPlus

Tags: python-2.7, flask-restplus

I have an endpoint that I decorated with `api.expect()`, but I am getting this error.

```
{
    "message": "Input payload validation failed",
    "errors": {
        "": "None is not of type u'object'"
    }
}
```

This is what my code looks like for simplicity.

```
@api.route('/history')
class ProfitAnalyticsResource(Resource):

    method_decorators = [jwt_required]

    @api.expect(api.model('HistoryParameters', {
        'jobId': fields.Integer(required=True, description='Job ID')
    }), validate=True)
    def get(self):
        """ Gets the profit analytics report for the current user"""

        return "test only"
```

I am testing this on Postman, passing in `jobId` as a url parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `api.model()`, I used `api.parser()`

E.g

```
@api.route("/list")
@api.doc(parser=parser)
class RoleListResource(Resource):
    method_decorators = [jwt_required]

    query_parser = api.parser()
    query_parser.add_argument('page', required=False, type=int, default=1)
    query_parser.add_argument('page_size', required=False, type=int, default=10)

    @api.expect(query_parser, validate=True)
    def get(self, query_parser=query_parser):
        args = query_parser.parse_args()
        page = args['page']
        page_size = args['page_size']
```